# making classes respond in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Am currently designing a website using bootstrap and so far I have come up with a very nice website that is supposed to respond but it doesn't when scaled down. I want the website to respond to the following screen sizes: 768x1024, 800x1280, 980x1280,1280x600 and yet I've read bootstraps docs of responsivenness and tried them but nothing has changed.

I created my own classes inside a getbootsrap template and even when I tried to put them inside;

```
<div class="col-md-4"><div class="andy-redbackground"</div>
</div>
```

even tried to get into the classes and insert:

```
background-size:cover;
```

but nothing worked out.

Comment: sorry i missed ">"at the end of andy-redbackground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:-

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="andy-redbackground"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```